# How to get the type of llvm::Value with lldb

Tags: debugging, llvm, lldb, llvm-ir

When working with LLVM IR, we can use LLVM Raw Stream to print the type of every llvm::Value. e.g.

```
void someFunction(llvm::IRBuilder* iBuilder) {
    llvm::Value* v = iBuilder->getInt64(0);
    // Print the type of value "v"
    v->getType()->print(llvm::outs()); // line A, get "i64" in stdout
}
```

However, if we want to debug some related codes, I don't think it is a good practise to modify the original code (add `print` function call) and compile again in order to get some debug information of value type.
So, assumed I have a break point at "line A", can I get some human readable type information (similar to "i64" in stdout) of `llvm::Value* v` in lldb?

Comment: `p v->dump()`, `p v->getType()->dump()`

Comment: @IsmailBadawi It works, thanks! Would you like to add it to answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As describe in the comment of @IsmailBadawi, we can use `p v->dump()` `p v->getType()->dump()` to print the target information (in `stdout` instead of debug output)